# 'wake up' or 'wake up at'?

Tags: prepositions

Which is correct?

> > the time that you wake up at
> >
> > the time that you wake up

Comment: Neither one is a complete sentence, so it's just about impossible to say "which is correct?" Either one could be used in a given context. See, for example, [this Google Books query](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+time+you+wake+up%22&gfe_rd=ssl&ei=8YNtV9DfJ4aX-wW_ipLgCw#q=%22the+time+I+wake+up%22&safe=active&tbm=bks), and [this Google News query](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+time+you+wake+up+at%22&gfe_rd=ssl&ei=8YNtV9DfJ4aX-wW_ipLgCw#safe=off&tbm=nws&q=%22the+time+I+wake+up+at%22) as well.

Answer (score 0):

In full it would be:

> the time at which you wake up.

However, in English we often shorten the relative clause (if there is no resulting ambiguity):

> the time you wake up.

Compare with:

> the person [whom] we met yesterday.